# How to upload file to pinata from react

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, node-modules

I keep getting the console error code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'

Shown below is the full console error code:

```
> triterras-node@1.0.0 start
> node triterras-nodeMVC.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\hp\Downloads\triterras-node-17November\triterras-node\triterras-nodeMVC.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I try to match node -v also but still facing issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough here to debug the exact error you're seeing as it doesn't appear to actually be an upload error or a Pinata error. However, as a basic frame of reference, this should help you with uploading a file from React to Pinata: https://docs.pinata.cloud/pinata-api/pinning/pin-file-or-directory#react